# Looking for the comic book where Spider-Man was [mistakenly] addressed as Super-Man

Tags: story-identification, marvel, comics, spider-man

I recently saw this snippet from what seems like an old Spider-Man comic where he's battling Doctor Octopus.

[image]

Here, Doctor Octopus is able to snap out of Spider-Man’s webbing after which he says:

> And now, **Super-Man**, I grow bored with this game! My time is too valuable!

I’m looking for the comic book where this occurred.

Also, did any of the publishers comment on this if it was just a typo, or some sort of mistake?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## It's from *The Amazing Spider-Man (1963) Issue #3*

The "error" occurs on panel 6 of page 7:

[image: Amazing Spider-Man]

Doc Oct already called Peter Spider-man on the previous page, so it does appear to be a mistake on the author's part.

[image: Amazing Spider-Man]

As a side-note, there's also that time where he was mistakenly called Peter *Palmer*. Granted, that was a clear misprint (given that the letter M is right below K on a QWERTY keyboard), unlike in this case where "Spider" is misspelled as "Super".

So one could assume that Doc Oct said that *on purpose*, to show that Spider-man's webbing wasn't indestructible, calling him "Super-man" (with a hyphen) just as he broke his webbing.

Comment: I don't think it's a mistake, Doc Oct is mocking Spider-Man, note as he says it he snaps the webbing.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I agree, I was halfway done editing :). That hyphen was there for a reason.

Comment: `k` might be right above `m`, but `r` is nowhere near `l`...

Comment: The reason so many Marvel Superheroes have alliterative names is so that Stan could remember them better. I've no doubt Palmer was a mistake by Stan that made it past Jack and onto the page. I seem to recall an instance where Bruce Banner was mis-named as well (separate from the TV show), and they gave him a middle name to keep it "canon". (source for most of these claims is the book Superman Is Jewish?: How Comic Book Superheroes Came to Serve Truth, Justice, and the Jewish-American Way)

Comment: @IronSean Damn you, autocorrect!

Answer (score 6):

This was from Doctor Octopus's first appearance in Amazing Spiderman #3 (from 1963)

You can see in this recording of the comic (crazy I know) on youtube:

It's also mentioned in this [archived reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Marvel/comments/1ui4fo/doctor_octopus_called_spiderman_superman_in_his/)

> Doctor Octopus called Spider-man Superman in his first appearance.

I couldn't find anything about it being a typo.